# Scheduling next shift such its not within X hours of previous shift

Tags: constraint, constraint-programming, job-shop-scheduling

Hey i have this constraint that i am trying to code in python: "scheduling next shift such its not within X hours of previous shift"
Given that i have start, end time of each shift and the user and shift dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose binary decision variable $x_i$ indicates whether shift $i$ is scheduled. If shifts $i$ and $j$ conflict, then impose a constraint $x_i+x_j\le 1$ to prevent scheduling both.

Answer (score 0):

if you know if task 2 should be after the task 1 then it is easy

$Start_2 \geq X + End_1$